# How do I write this matlab example to python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, porting

I am trying to convert this to python. I just really need help with 1 line. I nevered learn matlab

```
function   [xc,yc,R,a] = circfit(x,y)
%
%   [xc yx R] = circfit(x,y)
%
%   fits a circle  in x,y plane in a more accurate
%   (less prone to ill condition )
%  procedure than circfit2 but using more memory
%  x,y are column vector where (x(i),y(i)) is a measured point
%
%  result is center point (yc,xc) and radius R
%  an optional output is the vector of coeficient a
% describing the circle's equation
%
%   x^2+y^2+a(1)*x+a(2)*y+a(3)=0
%
%  By:  Izhak bucher 25/oct /1991, 
    x=x(:); y=y(:);
   a=[x y ones(size(x))]\[-(x.^2+y.^2)]; # i just need help with this line
   xc = -.5*a(1);
   yc = -.5*a(2);
   R  =  sqrt((a(1)^2+a(2)^2)/4-a(3));
```

Comment: Then I strongly suggest you learn enough Matlab to figure out what that line means!  See e.g. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f2-520.html.

Comment: The only difficulties I can see are: 1) `[x y]` is matrix concatenation 2) dotted operators (`.^`) are element-wise instead of matrix operations 3) ``\`` is left matrix division.

Comment: phg thnks. That is what I was having trouble with and i dont even know a thing about matlab. I never used it once in my life nor I will have a class to learn in a few years. 

@Oli Charlesworth-Normally, I would but I dont really like matlab documentation. It s a little hard to for me to understand and search through since it so huge

Comment: The documentation for MATLAB is one of MATLAB's greatests strengths. If you sit down and carefully study what you need right now, it does not take that long time.

Comment: i actually realize it, however, it is daunting for a newcomer is it is so large. There is a learning for for every language. I am not remotely near that curve for MATLAB. I am the type of person who crashes every program he ever used, so trying to get things right is much harder for me than someone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find [this reference](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html) useful.

- Matlab arrays are indexed starting at 1; Python arrays start at 0
- Python does not have a left-matrix-div operator, but numpy.linalg.solve performs the same operation

.

```
from numpy import matrix
from numpy.linalg import solve

def circfit(xs, ys):
    a = matrix([[x,y,1.] for x,y in zip(xs, ys)])
    b = matrix([[-(x*x + y*y)] for x,y in zip(xs, ys)])
    res = solve(a,b)
    xc = -0.5 * res.item(0)
    yc = -0.5 * res.item(1)
    r = (xc*xc + yc*yc - res.item(2))**0.5
    return xc,yc,r
```

then

```
circfit([0,1,2],[2,1,2])   # ->  (1.0, 2.0, 1.0) as expected
```